# How to evaluate $\lim (1+\frac1{2n})^n$ without L'Hopital, logarithms or Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How would you determine this limit without using L'Hopital's rule, logarithms, or taylor's series? Obviously this is equal to the square root of euler's number, but I am not sure how to prove that without these techniques, and do it mostly through factoring.

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1 +\frac{1}{2n})^n$

Comment: Did you try Binomial expansion.

Comment: The Euler number is defined as $\lim (1+\frac1n)^n$. Then transform your limit to something related to this limit, as Arthur hinted.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam : I don't think binomial expansion gives anything interesting here. But I'd like to be proven wrong :-)

Comment: What is your working definition of $e$?

Comment: Or just: do you know that $\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^n$ converges and to what?

Comment: the only definition we are working with for e is 
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1 +\frac{1}{n})^n$

Comment: In that case, note that the subsequence $a_{2n} = \bigl(1 + \frac{1}{2n}\bigr)^{2n}$ also converges to $e$, and you look at the sequence $b_n = \sqrt{a_{2n}}$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that makes it  pretty easy

Answer (score 3):

Hint: change of variables $n\mapsto \frac m2$.

Comment: Well, this answer is very good but notice that you changed a natural number by a rational one, so the OP would need some theoretic background to change the index of the limit process.

Comment: @Masacrosso Let's say $m$ is always even, and everything's good.

Answer (score 2):

You already know $\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n} = e$. Since we are dealing with positive terms, then:

**Hint 1:** $$\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)^{n} = \left[\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)^{2n}\right]^{1/2}$$

**Hint 2:** $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt{a_k} = \sqrt{\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k}\tag{by continuity}$$

**Hint 3:** $$n\to\infty \iff 2n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{\!n}=
\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{\!2n}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$n\geq 0$

Be $\displaystyle x_1:=(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{2n}$ and $\displaystyle x_2:=(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{2n+1}$ .

It's $\displaystyle x_1^{x_2}=x_2^{x_1}$ for all $n$ and therefore $\displaystyle x_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{2n+1}=x_2$ is limited and called $e$.

The value of $e$ is $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}$ and because of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ it's $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^n=\sqrt{e}$.

---

Derivation is allowed ? If yes:

The maximum of $x^{1/x}$ is with $x=x_1=x_2$ .

$\displaystyle (x^{1/x})'=x^{(1/x)-2}(1-\ln x):=0\enspace$ => $\enspace\displaystyle x=e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$